# How to find exact duplicate rows from table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am have a table containing 63 columns.

I am looking to find exact duplicate rows (all 63 columns) from this table, in mysql.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: So the table does not have a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to handle this as far as I know.  One option would just be a brute force `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., col63
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1, col2, ..., col63
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The above query would generate one record per offending duplication.  If you wanted to see how many records were in duplicate, you could add `COUNT(*)` to the select clause.

Comment: I was hoping if I could avoid putting 63 columns in the above query. Is there a way other than above?

Comment: Not without resorting to some sort of dynamic SQL.  By "dynamic" here I mean doing something like writing a code which auto generates that list of all columns.  By the way, while sometimes you might require this many columns, in general, you should avoid having tables with too many columns.